# Apply Multiple Columns to Custom function Using dplyr::mutate(across())

Tags: r

**df**

```
a = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb", "cc","bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb", "cc","bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb","bb") 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb", "cc","bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb", "cc","bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb","bb") 
c = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "cc","bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb", "cc","bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "bb","bb") 
d = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df = data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

**Col Names:**

```
cols <- c("a","b","c")
```

**Function:**

```
rare_label <- function(x){
  freq = prop.table(table(unlist(x)))
  make_rare = names(freq)[freq < 0.20]
  lapply(x,
         function(x) {
           replace(x, x %in% make_rare, "Rare")
         })}
```

Looking to evaluate with `dplyr::mutate(across())` the proportion of all values **combined** in a, b, c and then change any category with a proportion below 20% to "Rare".

**Output:**

```
     a    b    c
    Rare Rare Rare
    bb   bb   Rare
    cc   cc   Rare
    bb   bb   bb
    bb   bb   bb
    cc   cc   cc
    bb   bb   bb
    .    .    .
    .    .    .
    .    .    .
```

Using the code below throws an error and I'm not sure why.

```
df %<>%
  mutate(across(where(cols), ~rare_label(.)
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in: "  mutate(across(where(cols),
> ~rare_label(.) View"

Comment: your code on the first line does not work, one of columns is shorter

Comment: Fixed it, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(all_of(cols), 
               ~ replace(., . %in% names(which(prop.table(table(.)) < 0.20)), "rare")))

      a    b    c d
1  rare rare rare 1
2    bb   bb rare 1
3    cc   cc rare 2
4    bb   bb   bb 2
5    bb   bb   bb 3
6    cc   cc   cc 3
7    bb   bb   bb 1
8    bb   bb   bb 1
9    cc   cc   cc 1
10   cc   cc   cc 1
```

If you want to apply an existing function:

```
fun <- function(x) replace(x, x %in% names(which(prop.table(table(x)) < 0.20)), "rare")

df %>%
 mutate(across(all_of(cols), fun))
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that calculation through a function?

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 5):

Your code works well, just change pipe and values like this:

```
#Code
df %>%
    mutate(across(c(a:c), ~rare_label(.))
```

Output:

```
      a    b    c d
1  Rare Rare Rare 1
2    bb   bb Rare 1
3    cc   cc Rare 2
4    bb   bb   bb 2
5    bb   bb   bb 3
6    cc   cc   cc 3
7    bb   bb   bb 1
8    bb   bb   bb 1
9    cc   cc   cc 1
10   cc   cc   cc 1
11   bb   bb   bb 1
12   cc   cc   cc 1
13   bb   bb   bb 2
14   bb   bb   bb 2
15   cc   cc   cc 3
16   bb   bb   bb 3
17   bb   bb   bb 1
18   cc   cc   cc 1
19   cc   cc   cc 1
20   bb   bb   bb 1
21   bb   bb   bb 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is correct but you need to do 2 changes.

1. Remove `lapply` and keep the last line as :

```
replace(x, x %in% make_rare, "Rare")
```

2. Remove `where` from `across` since you are calling column by their names.

After doing those changes your code should work.

---

Another option is to use `forcats` package which has functions to do this kind of thing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(cols),fct_lump_min, min = n() * .2, other_level = "rare"))

#      a    b    c d
#1  rare rare rare 1
#2    bb   bb rare 1
#3    cc   cc rare 2
#4    bb   bb   bb 2
#5    bb   bb   bb 3
#6    cc   cc   cc 3
#7    bb   bb   bb 1
#8    bb   bb   bb 1
#9    cc   cc   cc 1
#10   cc   cc   cc 1
#11   bb   bb   bb 1
#12   cc   cc   cc 1
#13   bb   bb   bb 2
#...
```

`fct_lump_min` changes all the factors to "rare" which occur less than 20% (0.2 * n()). Here we are passing a number for `n` to drop levels, I couldn't find a function which works by passing proportion itself, `fct_lump_prop` does something else.