# Applying custom function to many columns in dataframe using across R

Tags: r, dplyr, custom-function, across

I have a dataframe, let's call it `ex_ds` with variables `v1` to `v15`

```
> head(ex_ds)
  v1   v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7   v8 v9 v10 v11  v12  v13 v14 v15
1  5 2014  1  2  4  1  1    8  4   2   2    2    2   2   2
2  5 2014  2  6  1  3  8 <NA>  1   1   2    2    2   1   2
3  5 2014  2  5  2  1  1    8  1   1   1 <NA> <NA>   1   2
4  5 2014  2  2  1  4  1    2  5   2   2    2    2   2   2
5  5 2014  1  5  2  1  8    7  4   1   1    2    2   2   2
6  5 2014  2  4  3  5  3    1  3   2   2    2    2   2   2
```

I would like to group by each `v1, v2` combination, and count the number of non-NA responses for each variable from `v3` to `v15`.

Here is my custom function:

```
n_fn_ex = function(var){
  n_var = ex_ds %>% 
    drop_na(var) %>%
    group_by(v1,v2) %>%
    count() 
}
```

It works for one variable specified individually:

```
> n_fn_ex("v3")
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   v1, v2 [1]
     v1    v2     n
  <int> <int> <int>
1     5  2014     6


> n_fn_ex("v8")
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   v1, v2 [1]
     v1    v2     n
  <int> <int> <int>
1     5  2014     5
```

But it doesn't work in my across statement:

```
ex_ds_1 = ex_ds %>%
  reframe(across(v3:v15, n_fn_ex))

> ex_ds_1 = ex_ds %>%
+   reframe(across(v3:v15, n_fn_ex))
Error in `reframe()`:
i In argument: `across(v3:v15, n_fn_ex)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `v3`.
Caused by error in `drop_na()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `1`, `2`, `2`, `2`, `1`, etc. don't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I've also tried the following which result in the same error:

```
ex_ds_1 = ex_ds %>%
  reframe(across("v3":"v15", n_fn_ex))
```

same with

```
n_fn_ex_2 = function(var){
  n_var = ex_ds %>% 
    drop_na(var) %>%
    group_by(v1,v2) %>%
    count() 
  return(n_var$n)
}

ex_ds_1 = ex_ds %>%
  mutate(across("v3":"v15", ~n_fn_ex_2(.)))
```

I followed the dplyr across page: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html and another post: [Apply Multiple Columns to Custom function Using dplyr::mutate(across())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731527/apply-multiple-columns-to-custom-function-using-dplyrmutateacross)

Example dataset:

```
ex_ds = structure(list(v1 = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), v2 = c(2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), v3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), v4 = structure(c(2L, 
6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    v5 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), v6 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    v7 = structure(c(1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), v8 = structure(c(8L, 
    NA, 8L, 2L, 7L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), v9 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 
    1L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    v10 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), v11 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), v12 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    v13 = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), v14 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), v15 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `across` (generally) applies a function to each column. But your `n_fn_ex` doesn't isn't really a function of a column, it uses the whole data frame! Inside your `n_fn_ex` definition you refer to `ex_ds` and `v1` and `v2`.... Write a simple function that counts non-NA values: `n_nonmiss = function(x) sum(!is.na(x))`. Not that this will work on any vector, and doesn't rely on anything else. Then use `across` to apply the function to each column: `ex_ds |> summarize(across(everything(), n_nonmiss)), .by = c(v1, v2))`. Or don't even bother with the function, use it inline as in Ze's answer.

Comment: But the key point is: make your function nicely general. Don't make functions that only work on one data frame with one name. You want to count non-missing values, so make a function that counts non-missing values. Then use `dplyr` functions to `group_by` and apply that function where you want. Don't put the `group_by` and the column name inside the function -- keep it outside.

Comment: `summarise(ex_ds, across(v3:v15, ~sum(!is.na(.x))), .by=c(v1,v2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't absolutely need to make a function for this, you can get the desired result with:

```
ex_ds %>%
  group_by(v1, v2) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(v3:v15), ~ sum(!is.na(.x)))
```

##### Update:

As @Onyambu commented, `summarise_at(vars(...))` has been deprecated, in favour of `summarise(across(...))`. You can rewrite the example above as

```
ex_ds %>%
  group_by(v1, v2) %>%
  summarise(across(v3:v15, ~ sum(!is.na(.x))))
```

Comment: consider using `across` rather than `summarise_at` which has been superseded